# Changing one select option changes many others (JavaScript, JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a lot of select drop downs on a jsp page with a long list of elements. All of these drop downs have the same list of elements. Say I have to get the choice in descending order of preference from the user. I made (many) selects in the following way:

```
<select id="sel1" class="myClass">
        <script>
         populate(document.getElementById('sel1'));
        </script>
  </select>
```

...

```
<script>
function populate(op1)
{

    var myArray = ["Chinese", "Italian", "Indian", ...//a long list of elements
        var sel = op1;
        for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.innerHTML = myArray[i];
            opt.value = myArray[i];
            sel.appendChild(opt);
        }
}
</script>
```

I have to create javascript/JQuery code in such a way that if a user selects an option the first select, that option gets disabled/removed in the others, leaving room for changes later. Say, the user's preference order is: Chinese, Indian, Italian... then on selecting Chinese in the first drop down, it gets disabled/removed from the other drop downs. Then, on selecting Indian from the second, it gets disabled/removed from all the others (including the previous one).
Now, if the user decides his order of preference is actually Chinese, Italian, Indian, .. he should be able to change his choice in such a way that the code doesn't break down. Say, we can have a button for reset and it resets all the choices by calling this function:

```
function resetFunc()
{
    var options = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
        for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) 
        {
            options[i].selectedIndex = "0";
        }
}
```

Any idea how to accomplish this? I need the code to be browser independent (while googling, I read somewhere that IE doesn't support removal of elements from drop down).

EDIT: Here's what I basically want:

http://jsfiddle.net/RaBuQ/1/

However, there's a problem in this. If a user keeps changing his choices, this thing breaks down. I'm able to select multiple choices.

Comment: Please create plunker or fiddle

Comment: @mplungjan: No, I did not, actually. But it did give me a jsfiddle example which also doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Because of this: `$(this).find("option").prop("disabled",false);` - it has to be conditional too

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry I didn't get that. This problem would mean running additional code to check if any of the choices are same. Can the choices be removed maybe? So that if there is a correction on the user's side, there's always a reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var v = $(this).val();
    $('select option[value="'+$(this).data('old-val')+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $(this).data('old-val',v);
    if(v != "0"){
        $('select option[value="'+v+'"]').not(this).prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/RaBuQ/199/)

If I selected 'Football', 'Golf', 'Tennis', I'd need to select 'No preference' in the third box before I could then select it in one of the other boxes. I think this is acceptable from a UX perspective.

Comment: That does work. A quick question - what are the onclick and onchange functions doing here-p1(priority1)? I didn't get that.

Comment: Much more elegant than mine (which I deleted) Only improvement I had was to generate the other selects from the options of the first using clone.

Comment: @user2816215 [The original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RaBuQ/1/) has those onclick/change functions. I've removed them in my example, but just haven't removed the tags. Feel free to remove :).  I've not included generating the `select`'s 'cos I thought you'd had that bit - you were just looking for a method to enable/disable 'already selected' options. Is that right?

Comment: Oh, right, And yep. Also, it works very well. Thanks!

Comment: @DaveSalomon  Yep, will do. Just one more thing - I put it all together - and there seems to be a problem: Here:http://jsfiddle.net/ignite9/m4szprxh/14/

Comment: Try and get out of the habit of binding functions inline. jQuery is all about binding via script. Instead of `<button onClick="...">`, you should `<button>`, and `$('button').click(function(){ ... });`. [Here's a complete _commented_ fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/m4szprxh/17/)

Comment: There's a teeny-bitsy problem here. This code disables all the selects that are modified so they actually don't get submitted in the form.

Comment: @user2816215 The code is disabling the `option` (which wont be the selected one), but not the `select`. It should be fine. A quick testing using $(form).serialize() seems OK? http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/RaBuQ/200/

Comment: Check this out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGWgaV
The problem is that I'm not able to get any of the modified selects on the servlet which is next. As in, say I select the second options from the 2nd, 4th and 5th selects out of 6 selects, then my url is:  sel1=0&sel3=0&sel6=0 instead of sel1=0&sel2=1&sel3=0&sel4=1&sel5=1&sel6=0. So if I try request.getParameter("sel2"), I get null.

Comment: @user2816215 Ah, I see! Yes, you're correct. `$('select').not(this).find('option[value="'+v+'"]').prop('disabled',true);}});` should do the trick. [Check it out](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbqWOY)

Comment: Yep, all okay now. I was trying to enable them all before submit, but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged this jQuery my example below will utilize that:

```js
function populate() {
  var myArray = ["Chinese", "Italian", "Indian"];
  $('.myClass').each(function() {
    var dis = $(this);
    dis.append($("<option>").attr("value", "").text("select"));
    $.each(myArray, function(i, o) {
      dis.append($("<option>").attr("value", o).text(o));
    });
  });
}

function init() {
  $('.myClass').html('').prop('disabled', false);
  populate();
}

$(document).on('change', '.myClass', function() {
  $('.myClass option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]:not(:checked)').remove();
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});

$('#reset').click(init);

init();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel1" class="myClass"></select>
<select id="sel2" class="myClass"></select>
<select id="sel3" class="myClass"></select>
<input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset options" />
```

Comment: Okay, I was trying this out. One problem - if I choose multiple times in one select, the choices get removed and then I cannot select the same choice in another select. Shouldn't maybe the whole select be disabled once a choice is made in that case? Otherwise, those choices cannot be in another select. For example, if I change my choice three times in the first box itself, there are no choices left for the next two.

Comment: @user2816215 that would be an issue. It can be fixed ofcourse, but I'm driving now and solving code issues is probably not recommended. I'll add something later

Comment: @user2816215 Alright, back on the computer and added a quick fix to the issue above. This will set the entire element as "disabled" once selected, since I didn't see any reason to do the same solution as Dave. If you prefer to disable the `options`, you can always mix and match solutions

Comment: yep, works now. The problem is which one to choose as the solution now. Both of your answers work. Ideally, your answer is according to what I asked, but I ended up liking the other answer more. +1 to you for your code. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thats fine @user2816215 - selecting an answer is totally up to you, and Dave's solution is fine. You can still use bits from my example since it might be a bit more complete. Glad to help anyway!

Comment: yep, I'll use this example in my project too!

Answer (score 0):

The following might not be the most efficient solution, but you should try it if there is nothing better: when you change a select, empty all other selects and then fill them with all the other options.

lets say you have 3 selects: sel1, sel2, sel3
 in the onchange event, you could call a function "fill_other_sel(number)" where number is the number of the current selector.

This function should delete current options and then populate checking with the previous selectors so that you dont populate with a previously selected value.

```
function fill_other_sel(number){
   var num_selectors = 3;
   while (number <= num_selectors){
      number++;
      $('#sel'+number).options.length=1;
      populate('sel'+number, already_selected_values_array);
   }

}
```

also you might add a parameter to your populate function showing which values have already been selected to prevent them from appearing again

Comment: That is kind of inefficient. This would mean running a lot of code when there can probably be a simpler solution.

Comment: i know, thats why i said "might not be the most efficient solution, but you should try it if there is nothing better" :)

Comment: I meant to add 'like you said'.